# WPF DatePicker US AND UK date format issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, date, datepicker

I have a DatePicker inside a datagrid in which the user can select a date like this

"07/04/2014" which is in dd/MM/yyyy, however, when saved to the backend, it appears in the database like 2014-07-04 00:00:00.000. (so in US)

I believe this is causing my problem in which when a user selects a date over the 12th day, the DatePicker becomes invalid and the user wont be able to save.

So for example if the user selects 13/04/2014 the datepicker becomes invalided as the properly thinks the format is in MM/dd/yyyy format (I believe)

How do I get around this? do I convert the DateTime property in the model to UK format, or do I need to set the format of the datepicker to something different?

Here is the XAML

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker Text="{Binding From,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}"></DatePicker>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

And the property in the Model

```
   public System.DateTime From
    {
        get
        {
            return m_From;
        }
        set
        {
           m_From = value;
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(From));
        }
    }
```

Any help would be good.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have conflicting cultures between the WPF application and the backend.

Comment: I believe so, I have just tried, 

                            <DatePicker Text="{Binding From, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>

but no help, is there a way to solve this in XAML or in the model?

Comment: Actually, are you passing the date as a `string` to the backend (perhaps via JSON)?

Comment: No this is a MVVM app, so I am binding the property to the datepicker

Comment: As mentioned, you need to check your regional settings on the client side, the server side and on the SQL database itself.

Comment: Also can you show the database save code?  As this is the most likely area that will need correcting.

Answer (score 1):

@GerogeHowarth helped me here,

I realised that the CellTemplate

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker Text="{Binding From,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Was passing a string back to the model, I should have been passing a date back

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding From,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
```

This has seemed to solved the problem.

Thanks